# MYSQL How to count the length of each word in text column

Tags: mysql, sql, text, string-length, word-list

Let's assume I have a simple table in mysql with a TEXT column named words which include arbitrary text, for example 'The big brown dog jumped over the lazy fox'.

How can I find the length of each word in the text using mysql query ?

The results should be: 3 3 5 3 6 4 3 4 3 - or something similar. Can be sorted, or can include the words themselves. Couldn't find my self to do that. I could find some samples of counting the number of words. But I need the LENGTH of each word.

Comment: _Can be sorted, or can include the words themselves_ what you mean?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The simple answer is: don't try to do this in mysql. Mysql is not renowned for its text processing capabilities. Any solution would include a stored procedure  looping through each text value and trying to identify individual words and getting their length. Identification of words is not that straightforward if you have normal text with punctuation and not just a list of words. Do this with a programming language that has libraries for this task, like python or r.

Comment: MySQL version ?

Comment: @Berto99 - means that the results of the query can have just the length of each word as I pointed or can also display the word itself and can be in sorted way.

Comment: @ysth - mostly not really relevant but let's go from 5.5 and up since the commands have not changed much

Comment: @Shadow - Thanks for that. I can do it quite easily in Python or PHP. But still, sometimes I like deep diving into MySQL and SQL even just to learn.

Comment: @aviv there are completely different ways to approach this for different server versions.  I'll do an answer for mysql 8 first, then if I have time add something for earlier versions

Comment: This is not going to be about sql, this will be about text processing in a programming language that was not designed for this purpose. The only way it is possible within reasonable timescales, if you have simplified text only (no punctuation, just list of words). Otherwise you have to write the word oarser yourself from scratch.

Comment: @Shadow yes, if this is actually about text and finding word lengths, you first have to define "what is a word", and any kind of accurate answer to that question is going to be only achievable in an actual programming language.   but it is being presented as a hypothetical, and the techniques for answering the pure hypothetical question in sql are useful in a number of real situations

Comment: @ysth you don't really know if the question is about just a list of words. The OP actually wrote: ` which include arbitrary text`, which could mean anything. There is no clarification from the OP that the question would apply to a list of words separated by space. This is an assumption on your behalf. Even if you make this assumption, what you get is a not particularly performant solution with no practical use.

Comment: @Shadow sure, I don't know.  the example is one point, and the wording of the question ("Let's assume"), and the vagueness about server version all put together make me think the particular question asked is not the real question.  Which makes me disinclined to say "just don't do it in sql" in answer to the "how do I do this in sql", as I might if I thought the question being asked was actually the practical question at hand.

Comment: @ysth why does the vagueness of the question matter? Had the question be more specific, would you have said not to do it in sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example doesn't show punctuation, so I'm going to assume you just want the value split up by spaces (so `The fox.` will give 3 for `The` and 4 for `fox.`)

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
    `bar` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
);
insert into foo values ('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'),('consectetur adipiscing elit'),('sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua'),('Ut enim ad minim veniam'),('quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat'),('Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur'),('Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident'),('sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum');
```

you can use a recursive CTE to get all the words in each text column:

```
with recursive words (word,remaining,word_number,full_string) as (
    select
        substring_index(bar,' ',1) word,
        if(instr(bar,' '),right(bar,length(bar)-instr(bar,' ')),'') remaining,
        1 word_number,
        bar full_string
    from foo

    union all

    select
        substring_index(remaining,' ',1) word,
        if(instr(remaining,' '),right(remaining,length(remaining)-instr(remaining,' ')),'') remaining,
        word_number+1 word_number,
        full_string
    from words
    where length(remaining)
)
select length(word) from words;
```

For earlier database versions without support for recursive common table expressions, you have to assume some maximum number of words and create a subquery that has rows with numbers from 1 up to that maximum.  For example, given a maximum of 256, you can say:

```
select i*64+j*16+k*4+l+1 n
from (select 0 l union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) l
cross join (select 0 k union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) k
cross join (select 0 j union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) j
cross join (select 0 i union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) i;
```

Or if you prefer, you can just use a long list of `(select 1 n union all select 2 union all select 3 ... union all select 256)`.

Then join that to your table and extract each word:

```
select
    length(substring_index(substring_index(bar,' ',word_number),' ',-1)) word_length,
    substring_index(substring_index(bar,' ',word_number),' ',-1) word,
    word_number,
    bar full_string
from (
    select i*64+j*16+k*4+l+1 word_number
    from (select 0 l union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) l
    cross join (select 0 k union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) k
    cross join (select 0 j union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) j
    cross join (select 0 i union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) i
) n
join foo on word_number <= length(bar)-length(replace(bar,' ',''))+1;
```

Comment: @aviv if this answer helped you, please consider upvoting it